# window.onload function can not be stopped

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am trying to use window.onload to initialize the page with struts2 action, but it falls into some kind of looping and keeps calling the init javascript function.

My code comes as follows:

javascript

```
<script>
    function init(){
        document.getElementById("test").action="test";
        document.getElementById("test").submit();
    }
    window.onload=init;
</script>
```

jsp file

```
<html>
    <body onload="init();">
        ...
        <s:form id="test" method="post">
            <s:select id="selectThing" onchange="init();">...</s:select>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not the cause for your issue but why you have `body onload` and `window.onload`? Both does the same thing.

Comment: @PSL oh...I thought that they should be together to make the initialization work...I will try to remove one and see how it works.

Comment: @PSL nah...removing either of them will result in no effect when refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

The `init()` will be called at each refresh, that is what you ask the code to do. Additionally why are you calling this in `onchange` event.

Comment: What I mean by "loop" is that the page keeps refreshing itself automatically.

Comment: @Z.pyyyy that's exactly what he explained. `init()` is called, then you submit the form, again I guess the same page loads and the form is again submitted and it keeps on submitting, because of body `onload`

Comment: Page will never refresh unless you asked it to do so. these is some trigger that makes it to refresh. Just disable each function call and see which one doing so